# Use Apport crash dump to debug Python program

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, coredump

I have a Python program that sometimes crashes due to a "double free or corruption" error. I am trying to figure out where this is happening (possibly in one of the many libraries I am using) so that I can prevent it from crashing. To that end I enabled core dumps, and I now have an Apport `.crash` file to work with.

Here's where I'm stuck. How do I load the core dump into gdb or something else that will let me see whatever stacktrace information is available?

apport-retrace seems like it would be great, but won't load because there's no package in the `.crash` file:

```
ERROR: report file does not contain one of the required fields: CoreDump DistroRelease Package ExecutablePath
```

I also can't figure out how to load it directly into gdb. I've tried `gdb /usr/bin/python <crashfile>` on the full `.crash` file, on just the "CoreDump" portion of the `.crash` file, and on a base64-decoded version of the "CoreDump" section. Each time I've gotten this error:

```
<crashfile> is not a core dump: File format not recognized
```

Is there a way I can either use apport-retrace without needing a package or pull the core dump out of the crash file in a way that gdb can use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out it was fairly simple to modify the `.crash` file to allow apport-retrace to open it. I simply needed to add

```
Package: python2.7
```

to the file. For good measure, I also made sure that the "ExecutablePath" was for Python:

```
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/python2.7
```

In my case, the executable path was previously a different file (one specific to my program). I don't know if this step was actually necessary.

After doing this, I could run `apport-retrace -g <crashfile>` to open it up in gdb and then use `bt` to extract the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

1) Instead of modifying the .crash file, you can add the `-R` switch to `apport-retrace`.  This generates a Packages: field, which particularly may be missing if there's a crash in package system itself.

Also, if you merely want to output the backtrace, you can use the `-s` switch in place of `-g`. `-g` loads the interactive debugger.  Together this may look like:

```
apport-retrace -C /tmp/apportcache/ -R -s -S system \
    /var/crash/$executable-path.$uid.crash > output.trace
```

2) An alternative is to disable apport by setting a kernel parameter and so produce a binary core file for use with `gdb -c`.

```
ulimit -c unlimited
sysctl kernel.core_pattern=/var/crash/core.%e.%p
```

3) See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash for a GUI method once you have apport-retrace installed.